# How to determine if ACE or JET on windows machine using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, jet

How to determine (for a machine running windows xp/vista/7) whether ACE or JET is installed, so I can use an appropiate connection string to connect to a access database.

Comment: Jet is always installed. The question is really only whether or not ACE is installed.

Comment: I think tag "ACE" is not appropriate here, because most of developers including myself think of Adaptive Communication Environment (http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) when they see "ACE" which has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: I have been trying to get a better tag than Jet (which overlaps with more than one completely different technology, and is also not accurate when it's the ACE instead of Jet involved), but nobody supports it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a registry key you can check. It is at `HKCR\Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`. You can read it using the [`RegistryKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) class.

Answer (score 6):

Agreed, the Registry is not the best method (32 and 64-bit versions as well as user permissions, etc.) However, the original question stated "use an appropiate connection string" - this is a runtime issue, not a compile-time issue.  A solution might be to use the OleDbEnumerator.

Here is an example that checks for the 32-bit version of Microsoft Access (ACE 12.0). for an x86 application:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

    static bool AceOleDb12Present()
    {
        OleDbEnumerator enumerator = new OleDbEnumerator();
        DataTable table = enumerator.GetElements();
        bool bNameFound = false;
        bool bCLSIDFound = false;

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
            {
                if ((col.ColumnName.Contains("SOURCES_NAME")) && (row[col].ToString().Contains("Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0")))
                    bNameFound = true;
                if ((col.ColumnName.Contains("SOURCES_CLSID")) && (row[col].ToString().Contains("{3BE786A0-0366-4F5C-9434-25CF162E475E}")))
                    bCLSIDFound = true;
            }
        }
        if (bNameFound && bCLSIDFound)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that the RegistryKey may be there but the OleDb connection can still fail because of 32bit / 64bit issues. 
If the target machine has 32bit ACE.OLEDB installed then make sure the app is compiled to target 32bit CPU. Otherwise the app may run in 64bit (on a 64bit OS) and then cannot load the 32bit installed version of ACE.OLEDB.

Comment: How can you check which architecture (if at all) of the provider is installed?